# How to email to specific user from dropdown after post

Tags: c#, linq

I have an MVC application where I'm trying to send an email after a user fills out a application.  The user chooses from a dropdown list on the application page which contains a list of administrators.  The email should be sent to whoever is chosen from the list.  I have An application table with the form information and a user table which contains the email.

***I have the following in my post Index action method in order to send an email after the application is posted. (Note: this works fine if I just pass in a static email into the mailMessage.To.Add method)***

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("myserver.net");
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();


mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@website.com");
mailMessage.To.Add(**need to pass in whoever's email is chosen from the dropdown here**);
mailMessage.Subject = "You've Received a New Application";
mailMessage.Body = "Please log in to view your new application. Thanks!";

client.Send(mailMessage);
```

***Here is what I need to do and what I've tried:***

1. Grab the applicationId from the application that was just posted
2. Join this with the matching UserId from the user table
3. Grab the email from the User table
4. Pass the email into the mailMessage.Add() method.

I tried this inner join query and tried passing sendEmail into the mailMessage.Add() method:

```
var sendEmail = from c in db.Applications
                            join a in db.Users
                            on c.FullName equals a.Id
                            select a.Email;
```

This gives me the error: "The best overload has some invalid arguments." 
Not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

***After some trial, error, and help...the working query.***

```
 var sendEmail = (from c in db.Applications
                             join a in db.Users
                             on c.FullName equals a.Id
                             where a.Id == application.FullName
                             select a.Email).FirstOrDefault();
 if (sendEmail != null)
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpout.myserver.net");
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("website.com");
                mailMessage.To.Add(sendEmail);
                mailMessage.Subject = "You've Received a New Application";
                mailMessage.Body = "Please log into to view your new application. Thanks!";

                client.Send(mailMessage);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your database structure, but your query is not filtering results based on the selected user. If you form has a dropdown of Administrators which are `User` and the value returned is the `User.ID`, then suspect you just need to query the `Users` table to get their `email` property

```
var userID = // the value from the post
var email = (from u in db.Users select u.Email where u.ID == userID).FirstOrDefault();
if (email != null)
{
  // create and send the email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get first or default on the Linq expression.  The linq result will most likely be an IQueryable which is an invalid argument to i assume the emails string type.

```
var sendEmail = (from c in db.Applications
                            join a in db.Users
                            on c.FullName equals a.Id
                            select a.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

This adds a where to filter your query and get the email you need.  I am not sure of the structure of your data, so i just assumed without much thought on that data.

```
   var sendEmail = (from c in db.Applications
                                join a in db.Users
                                on c.FullName equals a.Id
                                // where a.id = userIdValueFromDropDown
                                select a.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about FirstOrDefault.  Newb question, but how do I make the result a string so I can use it in my mailMessage.To.Add() method?

Comment: The result is a string.

Comment: Thanks.  Well all the logic appears correct and no errors, but the email isn't being sent.

Comment: @dc922 Check that the value of `sendEmail` is valid.

Comment: -2: you should say that `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if the sequence is empty. In particular, users of `FirstOrDefault` probably need to check for `null` before using the return value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sendEmail is indeed providing a valid email string, but it is only sending to the first email listed in my User table -not exactly the logic I was looking for.  Can't figure out why it's not sending to the person selected from the dropdown.

Comment: @dc922, Not sure I understand _only sending to the first email listed in my User table_. I cant see anywhere in you query where you filter the results based on the value of the selected person. What is the logic?

Comment: As Stephen stated its because there isnt a filter on the query.  

When they select from the drop down list you might take the name or user id in the value of the list and supply that as your filter value on the query.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to make this query.  I need to take the Id from the name in the dropdown list when the application is posted. The Id is the foreign key from my User table which is stored under the "fullname" column (yes weird) in the "application" table. I then need to somehow get the email from the User table that matches the ID.  Hope that makes some sort of sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry I missed your earlier post on filtering Stephen.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: Thanks guys - working great now.  Was just missing the "where" filter and "FirstOrDefault()" method.  Learning every day. Love this site!